# Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project2.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003)

Tags: c

structure array, got stuck at

```
    scanf_s("%s", name &stuarr[i].name);
```

error show :
Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project2.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003). Have seen others answer but cant fix it at all ...

```
#include<stdio.h>



struct student {
    char name[20];
    int rollno;
    float marks;
};
int main()
{
    int i, n[20];
    printf("How much students? :: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    struct student stuarr[20];
    printf("Enter name, roll no. and marks Below :: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter %d record :: \n", i + 1);

        printf("Enter Name :: ");
        scanf_s("%s", name &stuarr[i].name);
        printf("Enter RollNo. :: ");
        scanf_s("%d", name &stuarr[i].rollno);
        printf("Enter Marks :: ");
        scanf_s("%f", name &stuarr[i].marks);

    }
    printf("\n\tName\tRollNo\tMarks\t\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("\t%s\t%d\t%.2f\t\n", stuarr[i].name, stuarr[i].rollno, stuarr[i].marks);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the [scanf_s manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170). It requires an extra size parameter for `%s` (and for some other specifiers).

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &n);` That is also wrong. `n` is incorrectly defined as an array not an int. Change to `int n;`. Also, presumably you need to use it as the upper bound of the `for` loops. You may even be required to dynamically allocate the `stuarr` based on the input `n`.

Comment: Ērocne Ypsit, Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: `"%s"` will not properly read a name with spaces in it like "Ērocne Ypsit".